# Add some text to each line of txt file and pass to wget

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a file called : **filename.txt** *contains file name with extension*

I want to add url before each line like www.abc.com/

and pass it to wget like  :

```
cat filename.txt | xargs -n 1 -P 16 wget -q -P /location
```

Thanks

Comment: and what is the issue?

Comment: i want to do text change in same line of command..... @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: You may use `tee`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer, thanks to all for your valuable response

```
awk '{print "https://<URL>" $0;}' filename.txt | xargs -n 1 -P 16 wget  -q -P /location
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to **prefix** each line in `filename.txt` with a string:

```
sed -e 's#^#www.abc.com/#' filename.txt
```